# Stack around the variable is corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I have what seems like a pretty simple, beginner question that I must be missing something obvious. I am just trying to prompt the user to input a 4 digit number and then take in the input as an array, splitting up the digits to be by themselves. I thought it hade something to do with "cin >> input[4]" I just can't seem to get the right answer.

```
int main()
{
int input[4];       //number entered by user
cout << "Please enter a combination to try for, or 0 for a random value: " << endl;
cin >> input[4];
}
```

When I go to run it, I get an error message "Stack around the variable  was corrupted. 
I tried looking at similar examples in other questions but I just can't seem to get it right. I need the input as one 4 digit number and then split it up to a 4 position array.
If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `cin >> input;` You want the whole array, not just one character.  Also could do `int n; cin >> n;`.  Keep in mind there's a ton to learn about `cin` error management.

Comment: @ebyrob `cin >> input` won't work for an array of `int`s.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I realize that.  When I first read it I missed the unexpected `int` before input.  Of course, change `int` to `char input[4]` and the commented line of code actually does solve the problem if you use it correctly.  (maybe not advisably)  So, when I noticed `int` I left it...

Comment: @ebyrob Ah OK. I understand. (Yes, it would work with `char []`, but then we have a nice li'l buffer overflow, right? :/)

Comment: @H2CO3 Wow, are you telling me lil old `cin` is as bad as `gets()`?  That must explain my affinity for `fgetc(stdin)`.  But ya, `std::string` I guess...  I was thinking "obviously a new dev, one step at a time".

Comment: @ebyrob Exactly. In C++, prefer `std::getline()` over `std::cin::operator>>`. In C, prefer `fgets()` over `gets()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is of size 4, so elements have indicies 0 .. 3; input[4] is located behind the end of your array so you are attemping to modify memory not allocated or allocated for other stuff.

This will work for you:

```
cin >> input[0];
cin >> input[1];
cin >> input[2];
cin >> input[3];
```

You do not need an arry to input 4 digit number.

```
int in;
int input[4];
cin >> in;

if(in>9999 || in < 1000) {
   out << "specify 4 digit number" << endl;
   return;
}
input[0] = in%1000;
input[1] = (in-1000*input[0])%100;
input[2] = (in-1000*input[0]-100*input[1])%10;
input[3] = in-1000*input[0]-100*input[1]-input[2]*10;
```

Comment: one problem with this is that the user would need to hit space-bar or enter between each digit, otherwise you won't get 4 single digit numbers.

Comment: in the case with cin >> in; he does not need to

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to read **in a character that does not exist** (the one at index 4).If you declare `input` as `int input[4];`, then it doesn't have any characters at index 4; only indices 0...3 are valid.

Perhaps you should just use an `std::string` and `std::getline()`, and you could then parse the user input to integers however you like. Or you can try

```
std::cin >> input[0] >> input[1] >> input[2] >> input[3];
```

if you can live with the constraint that the numbers must be whitespace-separated.

Answer (score 0):

This includes a small bit of error checking:

```
int n = 0;
while( n < 1000 || n >= 10000 ) // check read integer fits desired criteria
{
    cout << "enter 4 digit number: ";
    cin >> n;   // read the input as one integer (likely 10 digit support)
    if( !cin.good() )   // check for problems reading the int
        cin.clear();    // fix cin to make it useable again
    while(cin.get() != '\n'); // make sure entire entered line is read
}
int arr[4];  // holder for desired "broken up" integer
for( int i=0, place=1; i<4; ++i, place *= 10 )
    arr[i] = (n / place) % 10;    // get n's place for each slot in array.
cout << arr[3] << " " << arr[2] << " " << arr[1] << " " << arr[0] << endl;
```